# Can i use if condition in spring xml bean definition?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have Spring Boot application where i use bean definition on xml.

I want to set bean property depends on my application's version. Can id do it?

Example how i see it:

```
 <bean class="Pojo">
        <property name="field" value="sample-value"></property>
        <if expression="version=3.0">
        <property name="field2" value="sample-value2"></property>
        </if>
 </bean>
```

Comment: No. But why not use java in which you can easily do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not switch to java configs, you can use a ref instead of value, implement a bean that checks the condition and returns the expected value.